# Query for calculationg percentage of many columns with a good performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, percentage, query-performance

I have some tables like below examples:

```
[myCategory]                      [mySales]
+------+---------+               +------------+-----+--------+-------+
| id   | name    |               | date       | cat | price  | code  |
+------+---------+               +------------+-----+--------+-------+
| 1    | cat1    |               | 2015/01/01 | 1   | 25000  | 2     |
| 2    | cat2    |               | 2015/01/01 | 2   | 32000  | 4     |
| 3    | cat3    |               | 2015/02/01 | 1   | 25000  | 6     |
| 4    | cat4    |               | 2015/02/01 | 3   | 40000  | 4     |
: ..   : ...     :               : ...        : ..  :        : ..    :
+------+---------+               +------------+-----+--------+-------+
   \---------------- Foreign Key ----------------/
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
[results are between @fromDate and @toDate]
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-...-+
| code | totalSale | prcntSale | ttlSaleCat1 | prcntSaleCat1 | ... |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-...-+
| 2    | 25000     | 20        | 25000       | 50            | ... |
| 4    | 72000     | 60        | 0           | 0             | ... |
| 6    | 25000     | 20        | 25000       | 50            | ... |
: ..   : ...       : ..        : ...         : ..            : ... :
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-...-+
```

> My problem is on calculating percentages.

Now I have declared some variable in my stored procedure  for each category and gather total of each `ttlSaleN` columns and then use them in the main query, that my solution should become faster, and I think I should change my solution.

My query is something like:

```
Declare @totalSale money = (select sum(s.price) 
                           from mySales s 
                           where s.date Between @fromDate and @toDate)
Declare @ttlSale1 money = (select sum(s.price) 
                           from mySales s 
                           where s.date Between @fromDate and @toDate and s.cat = 1)
...
select s.code, sum(s.price) as totalSale, sum(s.price) * 100 / @totalSale as prcntSale
               sum(case s.cat when 1 then s.price else 0 end) as ttlSaleCat1, sum(case s.cat when 1 then s.price else 0 end) * 100 / @ttlSale1 as prcntSaleCat1
from mySales s
where s.date Between @fromDate and @toDate
group by s.code
```

All these data are samples those I write them just now, if those have any problem ignore them ;).

I think using a single query for all that calculation can make it faster -*removing variables*-, If I'm in a wrong way please direct me to the right way.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear. Do you have any problem making single statement?  If no then just make another single query and compare. Without running both query on your production how can we assume some query is better then other?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I'm going to remove that variables those calculate sum values for calculating percentages.

Comment: That is pretty basic primitive query. I think you better optimize through indexes and statistics rather then through optimizing that query.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is really slopping compared to what I normally write, but I rushed through it. I'd recommend trying something like this though:

```
declare @myCategory as table(id int, name varchar(10))
declare @mySales as table(date datetime, cat int, price float, code int)
declare @fromDate as datetime = '2015-01-01'
declare @toDate as datetime = '2015-02-02'

insert into @myCategory
values
     (1, 'Cat1')
    ,(2, 'Cat2')
    ,(3, 'Cat3')
    ,(4, 'Cat4')
insert into @mySales
values
     ('2015-01-01', 1, 25000, 2)
    ,('2015-01-01', 2, 32000, 4)
    ,('2015-02-01', 1, 25000, 6)
    ,('2015-02-01', 3, 40000, 4)


SELECT      S.code, sum(totalSale) as totalSale, sum(totalSale) * 100/prcntSale as prcntSales,
            sum(ttlSaleCat1) as ttlSaleCat1, sum(ttlSaleCat1) * 100/prcntSaleCat1 as prcntSaleCat1
FROM
    (
    select      s.code,
                s.price as totalSale,
                sum(s.price) over(partition by 1) as prcntSale,
                case s.cat when 1 then s.price else 0 end as ttlSaleCat1,
                sum(case when s.cat = 1 then SUM(s.price) end) over(partition by 1) as prcntSaleCat1
    from        @mySales s
    where       s.date Between @fromDate and @toDate
    group by    s.code, PRICE, CAT
    ) AS S
group by    s.code, prcntSale, prcntSaleCat1
```